# Incrementing the last of a period-separated sequence of numbers in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, versioning, increment

I have a batch file which performs part of a software build process. It pulls the current tag name out of the build system, and puts it into a generated C source file. If the source is not being built from a tag, it gets the name of the latest tag (of the form 1.2.34 or 1.23). It then increments the "build number" by 1 and appends the text "Development". Or at least it should. Here's what I've come up with:

```
REM Increment the release tag. This will only work for Vx.y.z type release tags.
for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%A in ("!_lasttag!") do (
  set /a lastv = %%C + 1
  set "tag=%%A.%%B.!lastv! (Development)"
)
```

Input is in `_lasttag`, output is in `tag`.

This works fine for tags of the form "`x.y.zz`", but fails if someone makes a commit on a tag of the form "`1.23`".

Is there a better way to do this?

Ideally I'd like something which would work for any of the following version numbering cases:

```
1.2
1.2.34
1.2.34.56
```

My next idea (in terms of how to do this) was to iterate over the string with `FOR` to count the tokens, then do so again until the token count reached the last token. I ended up with this:

```
  set _nvertags=0
  for /f "delims=." %%A in ('echo !_lasttag!') do (
    echo %%A
    set /a _nvertags+=1
  )
```

But instead of looping through three times (with an input of "`1.2.34`"), it only ran once, leaving `nvertags` set to 1. Obviously I'm missing something somewhere...

Comment: not sure what the problem is exactly.You want to split the string with the numbers by `.` and to take which parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
for %%a in ("!_lasttag!") do for /f "delims=." %%b in ("%%~xa.0") do (
    set /a "lastv=%%b+1"
    set "tag=%%~na.!lastv! (Development)"
)
```

Just think the doted number is a file name with a extension. Get the extension, increment it and concatenate the rest of the elements.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `.0` in your 2nd FOR loop.

Comment: @dbenham, In the wrong case of `set "_lasttag=1"`, without "extension" the `.0` will force the second loop to evaluate and while the behaviour in this case is not stated in the OP question, at least it will not fail, generating a `1.1`

Comment: Interesting thought, but it might be better that the inner loop not fire since it is invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the MC ND solution, but without the extra FOR /F loop. I use a substring operation to eliminate the dot from the "extension"

```
for %%V in ("!_lasttag!") do (
  set "end=%%~xV"
  set /a "end=!end:~1!+1"
  set "tag=%%~nV.!end! (Development)"
)
```